# After p=new string[0] and p=new int[0], why the string version crashes when delete[] p?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator

I have two blocks of code about `new[]` and `delete[]`:

1)

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string *p = new std::string[0];
  delete[] p;

  return 0;
}
```

2) In this case, I merely change `std::string` to `int`

```
int main()
{
  int *p = new int[0];

  delete[] p;

  return 0;
}
```

**My question is:**

Why the first program crashes with the following message (in linux environment):

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But the second program works well without any error?

**EDIT**

compiler: `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2`

I just use `g++` without any argument to compile it.

If it is a compiler bug, should they crash or not according to the standard?

Comment: It doesn't crash here. Which compiler are you using (with exact version) and how are you compiling it?

Comment: Crash with g++ (4.7 & 4.8), doesn't crash with clang. I guess it is a g++ bug.

Comment: The program shouldn't crash. The reason why it crashes is that the people who made your compiler made a mistake somewhere. The only thing you can do is to rewrite to avoid the bug, or use another compiler :/ The easiest by far is probably the former. Do you really need an array of length zero?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be a gcc bug. That the whole `new[]` expression is ignored and `p` becomes uninitialized, and then we `delete[]` an uninitialized pointer which crashes. If we compile the program with `-Wall` it will warn you that

> warning: ‘p’ is used uninitialized in this function

which is clearly wrong. The expression `new X[0]` is well-defined in both C++03 and C++11 (§5.3.4/7), and this works correctly in clang, so the only logical conclusion is that it's a gcc bug.

---

The elimination-of-`new[]` bug only exists when the type to be constructed has any non-trivial constructor. And the segfault happens the type has a destructor, because the `delete[]` will then need to dereference that uninitialized pointer. Therefore, it crashes for `std::string` but not `int`, because `int` is trivial and `std::string` is not.

---

This can be worked around by using an intermediate variable, such that the expression cannot be evaluated to 0 directly:

```
size_t length = 0;
std::string* p = new std::string[length];
// ...
delete[] p;
```

Comment: I am surprised the hack works... On liveworkspace I have 3 behaviors: original OP code (warning + crash), this work-around (no warning, no crash), using `size_t const length = 0;` (warning, no crash). I *love* gcc...